# posting json to curl from asp.net core 2.0 HttpClient with additional information

Tags: asp.net, json, curl, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call below url from my code using asp.net core 2.0 web api:

curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data '{"key":"[your-key-here]","addr":"183qrMGHzMstARRh2rVoRepAd919sGgMHb","callback":"https://mystore.com?invoice_id=123","onNotification":"KEEP", "op":"RECEIVE", "confs": 5}' https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/balance_update

I created a Model to post with cURL like this:

```
public class ReceiveModel
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string addr { get; set; }
        public string op { get; set; }
        public int confs { get; set; }
        public string callback { get; set; }
        public string onNotification { get; set; }
    }
```

and calling it like this:

```
public const string baseurl = "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/balance_update";
public async Task<object>ReceiveBitcoins(ReceiveModel recd)
        {
            recd.key = "xxxxxxxx";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(rooturl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));

            var response = await client.PostAsync(rooturl, recd);
   return response;
        }
```

Please note recd is the ReceivedModel whose other fields are coming from WepApi post and api key is getting entered here only.

Is this the correct implementation? Do I need to take care of -H and --data, if so, how may I achieve this.

The response I get from this is :

```
    {"result":{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Length","value":["109"]},{"key":"Content-Type",
"value":["application/json"]}]},"statusCode":400,"reasonPhrase":"Bad Request","headers":[{"key":"Connection","value":["keep-alive"]},{"key":"Date",
"value":["Fri, 26 Jan 2018 11:31:19 GMT"]},{"key":"Via","value":["1.1 google"]},{"key":"Server","value":["cloudflare"]},{"key":"Set-Cookie","value":["__cfduid=dedf2c6d34e69eeeeeeeeec9b7f1516966278; expires=Sat, 26-Jan-19 11:31:18 GMT; 
path=/; domain=.blockchain.info; HttpOnly"]},{"key":"X-Blockchain-CP-F","value":["2fgz 0.010"]},{"key":"X-Blockchain-Server","value":["BlockchainFE/1.0"]},
{"key":"Strict-Transport-Security","value":["max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"]},{"key":"X-Content-Type-Options","value":["nosniff"]},{"key":"X-XSS-Protection","value":["1; mode=block"]},{"key":"Alt-Svc","value":["clear"]},
{"key":"Expect-CT","value":["max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""]},{"key":"CF-RAY","value":["3e33252b3fdd8a55-BOM"]}],"requestMessage":{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,
"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/json"]},{"key":"Content-Length",
    "value":["222"]}]},"method":{"method":"POST"},"requestUri":
    "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/balance_update","headers":[{"key":"Accept","value":["text/plain"]},
    {"key":"x-ms-request-root-id","value":["1e0xxxxx669-46xxx11d79afac17e"]},{"key":"x-ms-request-id","value":["|1e0xxx69-462511xxxxac17e.1."]},{"key":"Request-Id","value":["|1e0axxx9-462xxxx1xxxxe.1.1."]}],"properties":{}},"isSuccessStatusCode":false},"id":4,"exception":null,"status":5,"isCanceled":false,"isCompleted":true,"isCompletedSuccessfully":true,"creationOptions":0,"asyncState":null,"isFaulted":false}
```

This is

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you fill out this request through CURL, does it work? Is your "ReceiveBitcoins" method invoked?

curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data '{"addr":"183qrMGHzMstARRh2rVoRepAd919sGgMHb","callback":"https://mystore.com?invoice_id=123","onNotification":"KEEP", "op":"RECEIVE", "confs": 5}'

Comment: I have not checked, was just looking to complete every aspect. Do you mean to say, it can work even if we omit -H / --data?

Comment: You would have to instantiate the "recd" object before assigning the new value to the "key" property. You should add "recd = new ReceiveModel ();", before "recd.key =" xxxxxxxx ".

Comment: When I access callback url, I get what I used there as generally. Like nothing posted back from the blockchain server. I think it is the implementation of webhook but somehow failing to get it.

Comment: Is it possible for the help?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your doubt ...Could you give me more details?

Comment: In a nutshell, the point is how to get response from callback url as balance and how can I make that api work. There is no plenty example for the same, how to implement it.

Comment: Come on ... You are making a request from your server for the following service "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/balance_update". When you made your request, you defined your "callback = https://mystore.com?invoice_id=123" pripriety right? That is, when the "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/balance_update" service finishes processing your request, it will return the result for your "right callback"? However, within its "ReceiveBitcoins" method it only calls the service, and does not get that result. You wanted to get this result inside the "ReceiveBitcoins" method, right?

Comment: No, to my understanding, it should send it at my callback url and by calling that https://mystore.com?invoice_id=123. But the point is how will I get the balance amount at that url. I think it is something similar to webhooks. But don't know its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact, it will return the result for any callback URL that you enter ... Do you have the documentation for this endpoint "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive/balance_update"? In the documentation of this API, it tells you how it sends the data to your url callback.

Yes, in fact, it will return the result to any callback URL that you enter.

In order for you to receive this information, you must create a new method to receive this response, for example:

```
//This method is invoked via the url "https://mystore.com/balance-update".
public async Task<object>BalanceUpdate()
{
     // Perform the data processing here. According to the API documentation.
}
```

And in your callback, you specify the url to access this method "https://mystore.com/balance-update", meaning your callback would look like this "callback = https: //mystore.com/balance-update" .

Comment: The response you received in JSON means that some parameter is incorrect, it returned an HTTP 400 Bad Request. Review your parameters ... Post the API documentation. Is it easy to get a key to access this API? If it is, I'll try to use this service ...